# How do I keep my iframes responsive and scaled to fit their container?

Tags: theme-development, twitter-bootstrap, oembed, iframe

**This is a WordPress core question and only a CSS question as a byproduct.**

I am designing a theme using bootstrap. Everything looks exactly as I want it to with one exception - links embedded from my test blog.

[According to bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/embed/), there are utility classes for ensuring responsive iframes. However, this is markup from deep within the depths of WordPress and the block system.

It comes from `the_content();` like this:

```
<p><iframe ...></iframe></p>
```

The result looking like this - notice how the oembed has overflowed the right-hand side:

[image]

Is there a way to class those p tags (and only those p tags as `embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9` or similar or is there some other way to make the errant iframe get back inside where it belongs?

For example, is there something I can hook to alter the output of `the_content()` and specifically investigate which type of block each one is?

Comment: Did you use the **Custom HTML** block? If you did, you should be able to add `<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe ...></iframe></div>` or something like that. Or are you not using the Gutenberg editor?

Comment: This is straight out of the Gutenberg editor.

Comment: What block you used to insert the `iframe`? It was you who inserted it, right?

Comment: It's a link oembed (link to another post on same site).

Comment: Ok, but even so, what *block* you used to insert the link? The Paragraph block? The Classic block? Can you please be specific? Because using blocks like Paragraph and Custom HTML wouldn't give you that automatic `p` tags.

Comment: Nevertheless, with the Classic editor (or block in the Gutenberg editor), that `p` tags do get injected automatically. Yet, you can hook to `the_content` and replace the tags via `str_replace()`. E.g. `str_replace( [ '<p><iframe', '</iframe></p>' ], [ '<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe', '</iframe></div>' ], $content )`